# When to use static vs. intents for "global" instances of an object

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to instantiate an object in my MainActivity class that will be used and altered by my other activities.

The object is a custom data type.

Would it best best to declare the object as public static in MainActivity and then just use MainActivity.object throughout my application? Or would it be better to just pass the object around using intents?

The main thing I'm worried about using static is that I've seen people saying you use it when you care about privacy but I'm not too sure what that means so.. hoping to get some input.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of object is it? Also memory leaks aren't about privacy hehe.

Comment: you can pass the object through intents to change or alter.

Comment: First + foremost static is a memory tool, not an access tool. You use it to save and cut down on redundant objects in your code (e.g. if a variable is `"foo"` in every object, then it can be `static` and only exist in one true place). On a field, the combination of `public static` (without `final`) should always give you pause: anyone could just come along and `YourClass.SOME_FIELD = null;`, wrecking everything! This is very hard to trace, which is why it's important to encapsulate variables (don't make them public), and rather than "passing around" variables, it's either copying _or_ sharing.

Comment: @Rogue What do you mean by "anyone" can come along? You mean like my team members?

Comment: Your team members, your past self who worked on it at 3am, etc. In general, it allows too much to go wrong

Comment: Would it be okay to just do private static and use gets and sets or is that also dangerous? @Rogue

Comment: @jklo12334 it's less dangerous, but it isn't safe. You're still using static as an access tool in that way. You can code 95%+ of your program without any static. It helps to sometimes have a "central" class which is passed around that can allow you to utilize other subsystems of your program. That central class would be responsible for initializin everything. And then you don't need static

Comment: @Rogue Hmm okay, ended up sticking with passing around the objects using intents and startActivityForResult calls. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you need one object on all app, you can store this object in `Application` class